# Program not running in Cygwin64

Tags: cygwin, runtime-error

I'm trying to run a program (Exonerate : http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~guy/exonerate/) using Cygwin64.
But for some reason the program doesn't run when I try to execute it  using the Cygwin shell and produces no error message either. I've added the C:\Cygwin64\bin to the DOS PATH

The program runs fine in some other comp. which runs Cygwin32.

Can anybody please help to sort it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it print an error, or what you expect to happen does not happen?

Comment: the program takes many command line arguments, and when executed without any it just prompts the list of acceptable arguments. At present if run through cygwin shell produces no output to the screen. If I doubleclick thru' win explorer , it says "The application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application"

Comment: Previously if double clicked it was complaining about missing cygwin1.dll file butas I added the 'bin' folder to the path , it is not issuing that error anymore.

Comment: I don't see in your posting, **how** you run the program, and **what** response you get.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same situation in Cygwin64 on Windows 10. The solution is add `./` before the file name.

So that is when I want to run `test.exe` after I made it by running `gcc test.c -o test`, I need to run `./test.exe` instead of `text.exe`.